# getopt switch statement never hitting default case

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt

I've tried searching and haven't found a duplicate/similar question.

How come "default" is never triggering in this case? Working on some previous homework assignments for a course to prepare for the fall, and I'm having an issue with getopt() in C.

Here are the particular lines in question:

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'i':
            inFile = strdup(optarg);
            break;

            case 'o':
            outFile = strdup(optarg);
            break;

            default:
            usage(); //this prints the "usage" statement and exits cleanly.
        }
    }
```

My issue is, how come calling

```
./fastsort a b c d
```

doesn't print the usage and exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will search for options like `-i hello` or/and `-o world`

```
while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:") != -1)
```

However what you are executing is:

```
./fastsort a b c d
```

where `getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:") != -1` is not satisfied since none of the passed argument  `a b c d`is an option

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, and feel like an idiot:

Since there are never any valid arguments/flags given, the while loop doesn't even execute. I just added a little check beforehand, and it seemed to fix things:

```
//Check number of args
if(argc < 5 || getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:") == -1){
    usage();
}
```

Edit: Just realized it's not quite yet working. Now, since I'm calling getopt once too soon, it's dumping one of the args prematurely, thus not setting correct ones properly.

My new "solution" (albeit a bit hacky) is:

```
-Initialize inFile and outFile to null
-Do the while loop as in my original post
-If inFile or outFile are still null, print usage
```

And it passed all of the automated tests given.

Comment: I would consider `argc < 5`, that way if you have an additional option or more input later, your check still works, but doesn't automatically toss you into `usage()`.